# How to intercept uploading of email attachments with a Firefox XUL extension in outlook.com web mail

Tags: javascript, dom, encryption, outlook, xul

I have a XUL extension which uses a native Windows DLL and js-ctypes to encrypt files inside the local file system. I have already tested a menu driven version of it and it seems to work fine.

Now I would like to do the following: When creating a new email with attachments, be able to "catch" the attachment file and process it (meaning: encrypt it) before uploading to the composed email message. I would like to do it in a transparent fashion so the user does not have to go through the menu driven process except for providing the password for encryption.

I want to do this inside the outlook.com web based email (not Office version).

I know it is a long shot, but does anybody have an idea on where to start looking? Anybody has done something like this in the past?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good place to start is an addon that already does what you want (in a generic way):

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tamper-data/

On the download page it says `Use tamperdata to view and modify HTTP/HTTPS headers and post parameters`. You're interested in changing 'post parameters' so that's a good place to start.

---

But if you just want to implement this yourself....

I've answered this out-of-order, in order to progress in the way you might build up the solution in development.

In the final extension, you'll need to:

1. Intercept the request
2. Target the correct requests(s)
3. Get access to the POST request body
4. Parse the POST request body's form data (to get the real binary file data)
5. Do your encryption step
6. Re-encode the binary file data, re-assemble the form-data, and modify the POST request headers
7. Replace the existing content in POST request.

---

**Intercepting the request & replacing the existing POST content**

The basics are that you need to implement an [nsIObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Observer_Notifications) passing an [nsIHTTPChannel](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIHttpChannel) as the "subject" for observation. The "notification" you wish to observe is called `http-on-modify-request`.

There are simple examples ([1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Setting_HTTP_request_headers), [2](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Creating_Sandboxed_HTTP_Connections#HTTP_notifications)) for intercepting `GET` requests in the documentation for `http-on-modify-request`, however intercepting `POST` requests is more complicated.

**Getting at the POST request body:**

There's a [mozillazine forum thread](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=19&p=10418519) that deals with this exact topic. 
`Kamelot9`'s 2nd post in that thread details how to **(1)** get at the post body:

```
var httpChannel = aSubject.QueryInterface(Ci.nsIHttpChannel);
var uploadChannel = httpChannel.QueryInterface(Ci.nsIUploadChannel);
var uploadChannelStream = uploadChannel.uploadStream;
uploadChannelStream
    .QueryInterface(Ci.nsISeekableStream)
    .seek(Ci.nsISeekableStream.NS_SEEK_SET, 0);
var stream = Cc["@mozilla.org/binaryinputstream;1"]
    .createInstance(Ci.nsIBinaryInputStream);
stream.setInputStream(uploadChannelStream);
var postBytes = stream.readByteArray(stream.available());
var poststr = String.fromCharCode.apply(null, postBytes);
```

where `aSubject` here comes as a parameter to your `http-on-modify-request` notification. You can then just modify `poststr`. Depending on the server, you might also need to modify the `Content-length` header (or your post may be truncated).

**Replacing POST request content:**

Once you've got your modified POST body, you need to **(2)** replace the existing content of the `inputStream` in the `uploadChannel` with your own:

```
var inputStream = Cc["@mozilla.org/io/string-input-stream;1"]
    .createInstance(Ci.nsIStringInputStream);
inputStream.setData(poststr, poststr.length);
uploadChannel.setUploadStream(
    inputStream, 
    "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", 
    -1);
// do this last - setUploadStream resets requestMethod to PUT
httpChannel.requestMethod = "POST";
```

`Cc` and `Ci` above are just shorthand for `Components.classes` and `Components.interfaces` respectively. These shorthand variables may already be set up, or you can define them yourself.

**Parsing the form data:**

I think that normally for a file upload, the `Content-type:` will be `multipart/form-data`.

To get down to the particular 'attachment' you're interested in, you'll need to:

1. Parse the mime envelope to get out the file attachment
2. Find your file attachment
3. Remove whatever text encoding has been used (e.g: `BASE64`)

In the POST headers, you'll get something like:

```
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=JGUOAeGT3Fjgjcdk6s35F2mPVVyTdzgR
```

where 'JGUOAeGT3Fjgjcdk6s35F2mPVVyTdzgR' is the MIME boundary. In the body of the POST, the content will start will be formatted like this:

```
--[boundary]
CONTENT-PART #1
--[boundary]
CONTENT-PART #2
--[boundary]
```

Each `CONTENT-PART` above will have some HTTP headers, a blank line, then the body of that particular `CONTENT-PART`.

An example from another [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13574736/how-do-i-parse-this-http-post-request-in-express):

```
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="updates"; filename="update1353963418000.json"
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

{"collectionType":"activities","date":"2012-11-26","ownerId":"qw12er23","ownerType":"user","subscriptionId":"112233-activities"}]
```

In this case, the `Content-Transfer-Encoding` is binary (raw, encoded) UTF8, so you wouldn't need to do any more work to be able to read the JSON in the body of the `CONTENT-PART`.

In your case, the browser will be sending a binary file, so it'll likely have set the `Content-Transfer-Encoding` to `base64`, which means you'll need to Base64-decode the body of the `CONTENT-PART` to get to your real binary file. If `base64data` contains the encoded content, then this will give you the raw binary data:

```
var rawData = atob(base64data);
```

At that point you can do whatever encryption you want on `rawData`.

Remeber, you'll have to re-encode the binary data after your encryption (using `btoa`), then you'll need to re-assemble the multipart envelope, before re-constructing the POST request body. (Don't forget to get `.length` of the final request body so that you can substitute in the `Content-length` in the request headers.).

**targetting the request(s):**

That's the basic mechanism for modifying a POST request. But you've still got to single out *your* particular POST requests (examine the POST request URL in the observer notification) so that you allow other POST requests to proceed as normal without invoking your modification code.